# Updating the radius of multiple circles in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a map that shows a [Circle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple) with a radius of 50 miles around each set of coordinates in my array of locations. I want to have a series of buttons to increase or decrease the radius of every circle on the map on click. The way I have it right now, it is only changing the radius of the circle associated with the last location in my array. I understand why this is happening(because the circle variable is being assigned to each point in the `for` loop), but I am not sure how to change it so that the radius of each circle is updated.

```js
var retailerCircle;
var retailermap = {
 chicago: {
  coords: {lat: 41.878, lng: -87.629}
 },
 newyork: {
  coords: {lat: 40.714, lng: -74.005}
 },
 losangeles: {
  coords: {lat: 34.052, lng: -118.243}
 },
 vancouver: {
  coords: {lat: 49.25, lng: -123.1}
 }
};

function initMap() {
 // Create the map.
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 4,
  center: {lat: 41.878003, lng: -93.097702},
  mapTypeId: 'terrain'
 });

 for (var retailer in retailermap) {
  // Add the circle for this retailer to the map.
  retailerCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
   strokeColor: '#FF0000',
   strokeOpacity: 0.8,
   strokeWeight: 2,
   fillColor: '#FF0000',
   fillOpacity: 0.35,
   map: map,
   center: retailermap[retailer].coords,
   radius: 80467.2 // 50 miles
  });
 }
}

function updateRadius(circle, rad){
 circle.setRadius(rad);
}

$(function() {
 $('button').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  updateRadius(retailerCircle, 160934); // 100 miles
 });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<button>CLICK ME</button>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for update @geocodezip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep references to all the circles (in an array would be one option), then iterate through that array, updating the radius.

```
function updateRadius(circle, rad) {
  for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
    circles[i].setRadius(rad);
  }
}
```

**code snippet:**

```js
var retailerCircle;
var circles = [];
var retailermap = {
  chicago: {
    coords: {
      lat: 41.878,
      lng: -87.629
    }
  },
  newyork: {
    coords: {
      lat: 40.714,
      lng: -74.005
    }
  },
  losangeles: {
    coords: {
      lat: 34.052,
      lng: -118.243
    }
  },
  vancouver: {
    coords: {
      lat: 49.25,
      lng: -123.1
    }
  }
};

function initMap() {
  // Create the map.
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {
      lat: 41.878003,
      lng: -93.097702
    },
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });

  for (var retailer in retailermap) {
    // Add the circle for this retailer to the map.
    var retailerCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map,
      center: retailermap[retailer].coords,
      radius: 80467.2 // 50 miles
    });
    circles.push(retailerCircle);
  }
}

function updateRadius(circle, rad) {
  for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
    circles[i].setRadius(rad);
  }
}

$(function() {
  $('button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    updateRadius(retailerCircle, 160934); // 100 miles
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<button>CLICK ME</button>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
```